# Allocate an Array of 999999999 cells | C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, new-operator

If I compiled this:

```
long double *N;

N = new long double[999999999];
```

I get this error:

```
error C2148: total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes
```

So, I tried compiling this:

```
long double *N;
long double *N2;

N = new long double[999999999];
N2 = N + 99999999;
N2 = new long double[900000000];
```

I still didn't run the program, but I'm pretty sure that I'll get a `heap corruption detected` error because I don't want to navigate with N then at a certain point navigate with N2.

**Is there a safe why to do this with only one pointer ?**

Comment: Do you have that much memory? Also, you must be using a very old version of MSVC to be getting error C2148.

Comment: This is compiler, architecture (X86 32 bits or x86-64 64 bits?), and system dependent. So you should much more details to get an answer. However, the compiler is probably right: there is not way to allocate a billion doubles on your machine (which should eat 8Gbytes; are you sure you have enough RAM?)

Comment: It compiles fine in VS2010. Also, `long double` is the same as `double` in MSVC.

Comment: That's way over 2GB, is it 64 bit compiler?

Comment: @jonas You can't use more than 2GB in x86 on Windows. This code requires almost 8GB.

Comment: But why do you have to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to write a library for big numbers (just training) 999999999 * ( [i=1]Σ[999999999] 1000000000 ^ i )

Comment: Why do you allocate them all at ones? Cant you allocate memory when needed and release after use?

Comment: @Mysticial you can use more than 2GB in x86 on Windows. The limit is 16TB. You just can't map more than 2GB at once into your address space.

Comment: @jonas What's `N2 = N + 99999999;` for?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes If you're talking about [PAE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that's up to 64GB. But total in the system. Per-process it's still limited to 2GB I think.

Comment: @Mystical + R.Martin: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx -> `The maximum 32-bit limit of 128GB, supported by Windows Server 2003 Datacenter Edition`

Comment: @Mysticial No, I'm not talking about *physical memory*. I'm also not talking about *virtual address spaces*. I'm talking about *virtual memory*. Each process can allocate up to 16TB, and have up to 2GB of those 16TB mapped at any time. See here a post by Raymond Chen where he shows how to allocate 4GB and map a portion of it: https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/10/211890.aspx

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes That's interesting. At first glance it sounds like some sort of manual swapping mechanism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

999999999*sizeof(double) is 7999999992 bytes. On a 32-bit platform, that is way more than 2^32 bytes. You simply can't address that many bytes in a 32-bit application.

If you absolutely must have 1 billion doubles, use a 64-bit platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a 64bit platform and has enough RAM to support the memory allocation the compiler wont generate any error. If either of the condition is false the compiler generates error or exception and there is no "safe" way to allocate memory beyond Ram or more than what is supported by the OS and processor.